# How To Post api call without use of CURL

Tags: php

I Try the following code to run my cron inside any function but it not working

```
$url = "http://example.com";

    $header = array(
        "Content-type" => "application/json",
        "x-user-agent"=> "shkasdksajd"
    );

    $context_options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST'
            , 'header' => $header
           
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($context_options);
    $page = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    echo $page;
```

it shows internal server error but it running on the postman

Comment: Are you getting any specific error messages?

Comment: internal servererror

Comment: Do you have access to the web server's error logs to look for more specific information about what is going on?

Comment: In fact, you'll find a PHP-code mistake in another place, which doesn't relevant to this question and that's all.

Comment: `$url = "myurl.com";`is no URL. Add the scheme `$url = "http://myurl.com";`.

Comment: i know  myurl.com is not exist i just write to understood that  i dont want to expose my url '

Comment: "But it running on the postman", try to [generate the php code with postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you Can use `CURL` with `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`

like that

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "your url",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "x-user-agent: your_x-user-agent_key"
  ),
));
```

may it helps

Comment: yes its work for me it give me response in cron and postman too

Answer (score 0):

Sending an HTTP POST request using [`file_get_contents`](http://fr.php.net/file_get_contents) is not that hard, actually : as you guessed, you have to use the `$context` parameter.

There's an example given in the PHP manual, at this page : [HTTP context options][2] *(quoting)* :
```
$url = "http://myurl.com/";
    $postdata = json_encode(
        array(
            'var1' => 'some content',
            'var2' => 'test content'
        )
    );
    
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/json',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );
    
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```
Basically, you have to create a stream, with the right options *(there is a full list on that page)*, and use it as the third parameter to `file_get_contents` -- nothing more ;-)

As a sidenote : generally speaking, to send HTTP POST requests, we tend to use curl, which provides a lot of options an all -- but streams are one of the nice things of PHP that nobody knows about... too bad...